# How do I pass a collection from a parent partial to an arbitrary sub-partial depth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

I'm following the RailsTutorial, and I'm currently stuck on [exercise 10.5.5](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts?version=3.2#sec%3amicropost_exercises). Since I'm changing quite a bit, I've put the code into a [paste](http://pastebin.com/yQf5Mcww) (updated).

There are a few things to note before going into the paste:

1. One of the original partials receives a collection from it's "parent" partial, while the other receives the object directly from the controller.
2. The `if` statement in both of these "child" partials uses a different object name, but they're represent the same object in the database.

Ideally, I'd like to move the `if` statement into the grandchild, or sub-sub-, partial. I can leave it in the child partial if need be, but this doesn't feel DRY.

I've tried rendering the grandchild partial with `<%= render partial: 'shared/foo', object: bar, as: :baz %>` so I can use `baz` in the grandchild partial, since the other child partial uses `baz` by default. In that partial, I'm just doing `<%= render partial: 'shared/foo', object: baz %>`. Confused? Me, too.

You'll notice I've tried rendering the partials both with and without passing in the parent object. Maybe the parent object needs to be redefine? I also just tried `<%= render partial: 'shared/micropost_delete_link', object: feed_item %>`, but no luck.

Each approach I've tried so far yields the same error in the tests:

```
 Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `user' for :feed_item:Symbol
```

This seems to indicate that I can't pass a single object received from the parent option `collection: @feed_items`.

**Update:** There was a typo in my original paste. With that fixed in the updated paste, my tests are still failing.

```
 Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere along the line, I tried a different syntax, and the tests started passing:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/micropost_delete_link', locals: { micropost: feed_item } %>
```

Even though [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.0/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) say the following should be equivalent:

```
<%= render :partial => "account", :object => @buyer, :as => 'user' %>
<%= render :partial => "account", :locals => { :user => @buyer } %>
```

Testing is still a bit unusual for me, so I can't rule out that it forced something in the suite to be re-evaluated.

Comment: The first example -> 'locals: { micropost: feed_item }' is the way to go.